The minimum set of vertices belonging to maximal cliques
Let $G$ be a simple graph of diameter $2$ on $n$ vertices. Suppose we want to find a set of vertices $S$ such that each maximal clique in $G$ contains at least one vertex from $S$. Let's call this set a clique core. $S$ is a minimum clique core if there exists no clique core on fewer than $\lvert S\rvert$ vertices.
What's the asymptotic formula for the maximum possible size of a minimum clique core of $G$?
